# Unable to import cartopy: ImportError: libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, conda, cartopy

I am having trouble importing cartopy in a newly created conda environment. I installed cartopy with

`conda install -c conda-forge cartopy`

but when I try to import it I run into the following error:

ImportError: libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I do have libgeos in my enviroment lib directory, but still it doesn't work.

I tried doing what is suggested here: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/302
and manually adding the library path :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

but still not working. I don't know what else to do. It was working just fine before, but after I had to reinstall miniconda because of another issue I was having, I haven't been able to install cartopy.

I'm using conda 4.9.2 and python 3.9.1.

Comment: Could you please try creating a new environment (`conda create -n foo -c conda-forge cartopy`)? And ensure that all packages come from Conda Forge. One should not have to mess with env vars, especially not forcing something outside the environment to be prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

Around December 2022, there were some changes with a cartopy dependency shapely, a solution that worked for me was found in the following stackoverflow answer: [Getting "AttributeError: module 'shapely.geos' has no attribute 'lgeos'"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75223705/1480918)

For newer version of Conda 23.7.2, I have the following dependencies working. However best to update your code to support newer versions of cartopy.

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - cartopy=0.18.0
  - geopy=2.2.0
  - python=3.9
  - pip=23.2.1
  - pip:
    - shapely==1.8.5
```